# Как создать запрос по уникальным значениям по двум полям

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица с данными, СУБД Sql Server. Там есть 2 поля типа Text, необходимо создать запрос, который бы вывел все записи, в которых были бы значение - 1 поле + 2 - уникальные. Как это можно прописать?

Пример, например с машинами, есть 3 поля через точку:

```
 1. Рено.Красный.21592
 2. Рено.Синий.21590
 3. Шевроле.Зеленый.59181
 4. Рено.Красный.59186
```

Вот, необходимо вывести так, чтобы Рено.Красный был только 1 раз.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: @Akina это да, но он выводит по 1 полю просто.. А, в итоге в скобках просто пропишу одно поле + второе и всё заработало, спасибо)

Comment: Ничего не понял... но если заработало, то и ладно.

Comment: select distinct поле1,поле2, поле3 from table